# Redirect POST-request in apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm trying to do a transparent redirect of a post-request in my apache server.

The request looks like this:

```
POST www.domain.com//maincontroller.php/api
```

I want to redirect this to:

```
POST www.domain.com/maincontroller.php/api
```

I don't want a 301 redirect but instead a silent redirect (edit the Post address and send it to httpd).

Everything I tried with `mod_rewrite` didn't rewrite the POST, but successfully rewrote a GET.

Comment: what do you exactly mean by silent redirect?

Comment: I want to modify the address before sending it (again ?) to httpd so It can be interpreted.

Answer (score 0):

Coworker found it !

```
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} POST
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s//+(.*)\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$ [OR]
    RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s(.*/)/+\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$
    RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [P]
```